# pip error calling lsb_release when installing new package

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to configure 2 Ubuntu servers to use Python and Tensorflow for my project. I finished the 1st server, however, there are some very unusual and annoying errors with the 2nd one. This is the log when I run pip check on the 1st server:

```
~$: pip check
No broken requirements found.
```

And the error log on the 2nd one:

```
~$: pip check
No broken requirements found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 251, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 72, in _build_session
    insecure_hosts=options.trusted_hosts,
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/download.py", line 329, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/download.py", line 93, in user_agent
    from pip._vendor import distro
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 1050, in <module>
    _distro = LinuxDistribution()
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 594, in __init__
    if include_lsb else {}
  File "/home/mju-hpc-02/.local/lib/python3.5/site-
  packages/pip/_vendor/distro.py", line 931, in _get_lsb_release_info
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(code, cmd, stdout, stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero 
exit status 1
```

This error also shows everytime I'm trying to install a new package with pip. Anyone faced similar problems with pip or having a way to diagnose the error?

**EDIT 1:**

As languitar suggestion, I ran lsb_release -a on both machines and this is the log on the 1st one:

```
~$: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

2nd one:

```
~$: lsb_release -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/lsb_release", line 25, in <module>
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'
```

Comment: So what happens if you call `lsb_release -a` manually? ;)

Comment: @languitar: I updated the post as your suggestion. Maybe I should try to find a solution for that last line

Comment: Your second server seems to be missing a correctly installed `lsb_release` binary. Try to reinstall `lsb-release` (ubuntu or debian package).

Comment: I think I wasted my whole day for this dumb error... Thank you so much :) Can you make your comment as an answer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your `lsb_release` binary is broken. Try to reinstall `lsb-release` (ubuntu or debian package).

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention your Python version(s) available on your system.
Not sure how this happen, but often 'lsb_version' is available to run on python v2 and others on v3.
Most likely you have a multiple python version on your host.

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'lsb_release -a' returned non-zero 
exit status 1
```

Is, indeed, failing because the 'lsb_release' library called by '/usr/bin/lsb_release' is not available for your particular Python version.
Your first attempt to fix this is simple:

```sh
sudo apt install lsb-release
```

<sub>Note is `'-'` and not `'_'`</sub>

Try again, if keep failing try the following: Look for your Python version library on /usr/lib, and confirm that 'lsb_release.py' is not there. Then, link the shared version to your library:

```sh
ln -sfv /usr/share/pyshared/lsb_release.py /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lsb_release.py
```

Last resource, search `/usr` for any `lsb_release.py` and link it to your Python library.

```sh
find /usr -name lsb_release.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [default lsb_release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lsb/files/lsb_release/1.4/lsb-release-1.4.tar.gz) or perhaps a bit modified version:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash

171     [ -z "$LSB_VERSION" ] && LSB_VERSION="1.4"

172 #$MSG_NA
```